# Preventing sql injection with stored procedures

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm calling a system stored procedure for full text search package. It generates terms used for full text search based on a sql literal.

ex: exec ctx_query.explain('index_name', 'full text filter', 'explain table') etc

I'm doing the following in my code:

```
using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("ctx_query.explain", DataAccess.GetConnString()))
{   
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("index_name", "explain1");
    //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("text_query", "(test) OR (term1 ACCUM term2");
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("text_query", txtUserInput.Text);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("explain_table", "explain_results");
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("sharelevel", 0);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("explain_id", new Guid().ToString().Substring(0,30));
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}
```

The "text_query" parameter will be built from user input. Does the above prevent sql injection because the textUserInput.Text will be passed as a command parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ctx_query.explain](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqrypkg.htm#i996934) does not **execute** the query, it only examines it, so there is no SQL injection risk here.

Comment: But can't someone enter '"); DELETE FROM table as the user input?

Comment: Yes, and `ctx_query.explain` will **examine and report on** that.  It will not **execute** it.